# Import CSS file with Fonts in VueJS

Tags: css, fonts, vue.js, font-face, vue-component

I have a Vue application and I want use a line-awesome font. But in my **App.vue** that is my component I import css file fonts in this way:

```
@import 'assets/fonts/line-awesome/css/line-awesome.min.css';
```

My problem is that no errors are shown, but my fonts are not loaded in my app.

In that css file, it contains this font face:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "LineAwesome";
  src: url("../fonts/line-awesome.eot?v=1.1.");
  src: url("../fonts/line-awesome.eot??v=1.1.#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("../fonts/line-awesome.woff2?v=1.1.") format("woff2"),
       url("../fonts/line-awesome.woff?v=1.1.") format("woff"),
       url("../fonts/line-awesome.ttf?v=1.1.") format("truetype"),
       url("../fonts/line-awesome.svg?v=1.1.#fa") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Now I don't know if my problem is because my path is wrong setted or I need a additional configuration in my app.

Some idea about how I can fix it?

Comment: did created vue app using vue-cli ?

Comment: Yes, I do it by vue-cli.

Comment: Instead of placing `assets` directory place in `static` directory. And point like as `@import '/staic/fonts/line-awesome/css/line-awesome.min.css'; `

Comment: I config this static path and now is working! But before I were Do it, I setup somethings in my webpack config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your files under static directory and link like

> @import '/staic/fonts/line-awesome/css/line-awesome.min.css';

Files in static/ are not processed by Webpack at all: they are directly copied to their final destination as-is, with the same filename.

Some serious issue with line-awesome css and fonts. Even I loaded using normal simple HTML site with source css and fonts (http://maxcdn.icons8.com/fonts/line-awesome/1.1/line-awesome.zip) its giving box symbol as an icon.

Sample code which I used for test  source is below

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./la/css/line-awesome-font-awesome.css">
</head>
<body>
<i class="fa fa-file-word-o"></i>
</body>
</html>
```

Output as follows

[image: Output of line awesome]

But if you use cdn like as follows

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/fonts/line-awesome/1.1/css/line-awesome-font-awesome.min.css">`

Comment: I solved this problem following your suggest and I did some configurations in my webpack.config.js to set publicPath. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for this help! If possible you can vote my question?